# WinSCP - LS Command Line Syntax?

Tags: winscp

I've had good success using WinSCP (via VBA from MSAccess) for FTP Put and Get functions.

Next up, I'd like to be able to inspect the remote FTP directory to confirm a file exists, but I am getting hung-up on syntax, I think.  Here's the command I am trying to use (tried from .bat and at C:\ prompt):

```
WinSCP.com /command ""open ftp://user:password@ftp-example.egnyte.com/"" ""ls /Shared/Backend_Databases/*.zip"" ""exit""
```

The command seems to run but presents a "Host:" prompt, then quits.  What is WinSCP looking for here?  Do I have the double-quotes properly employed?

Thanks for any guidance,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will be wrong, `""` will be treated as an empty string and then `open` will be treated as a string without your server address.

Try remove all duplicated double quotes.

`WinSCP.com /command "open ftp://user:password@ftp-example.egnyte.com/" "ls /Shared/Backend_Databases/*.zip" "exit"`

Comment: That's correct. The double double quotes are possibly coming from OP's VBA string literal, where the double quotes needs to be doubled.

Comment: Yes, replacing double quotes to single was the key!  They seemed necessary for the other Put & Get functions (after much trial and error).  Thank you, both.